how to open this dialog in android studio koala 2024.1.1
I want to know where can I open the proxy setup dialog for gradle proxy ? below ,it opened after I click gradle sync. but I want to open the setup dialog in the file/Setting,but I cant find it.

below it is system proxy for Android Studio ,not for gradle.

I want to find it and set it.
